# Choose 2nd observation from a participant in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am working on a dataset that has several observations for each participant. Whenever there are more than 1 observation for a participant, I want to choose the 2nd observation for this participant.

Here is an example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
date_of_exam=c("2020-07-28", "2020-05-28", "2020-05-30", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-07", "2020-03-20"))
```

I thought about using an if else function:

```
df%>%
arrange(date_of_exam)%>% 
mutate(date_new = ifelse(count(ID)>1, slice(date_of_exam, 2), date_of_exam))
```

How can I make this work?

Also, does slice(date_of_exam, **2**) always take the **2**nd observation for each participant. Is this the correct function to use?

Thanks so much,

Phil

Update:
Now I want to create another condition, therefore I use another example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
date_of_exam=c("2020-07-28", "2020-05-28", "2020-05-30", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-07", "2020-03-20"),
date_of_biopsy=c("2020-07-20", "2020-05-29", "2020-06-01", "2020-03-05", NA, NA, NA))
```

Now I want this condition: if (date_of_exam-date_of_biopsy<0)==True, then take the 2nd value, otherwise take the first value.

Ronak Shah's code worked for choosing the 2nd observation, but whenever I put in the following ifelse condition, I get this error:
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `new`.
x Input `new` can't be recycled to size 3.

This is the code the error refers to:

```
df%>%
group_by(ID)%>%
mutate(data_new= ifelse((date_of_exam-date_of_biopsy<0)==True, mutate(new_date = date_of_exam[min(n(), 2)]), min(date_of_exam)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min(n(), 2)` to select minimum of 2 or number of rows in the group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(min(n(), 2)) %>% ungroup

#  ID    date_of_exam
#  <chr> <chr>       
#1 A     2020-07-28  
#2 B     2020-05-30  
#3 C     2020-03-05
```

If you want to add that as a new column :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(new_date = date_of_exam[min(n(), 2)]) %>%
  ungroup

#  ID    date_of_exam new_date  
#  <chr> <chr>        <chr>     
#1 A     2020-07-28   2020-07-28
#2 B     2020-05-28   2020-05-30
#3 B     2020-05-30   2020-05-30
#4 C     2020-03-03   2020-03-05
#5 C     2020-03-05   2020-03-05
#6 C     2020-03-07   2020-03-05
#7 C     2020-03-20   2020-03-05
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's amazing! Now I was trying to add another condition. I have two dates: date_of_exam and date_of_biopsy and want something like that mutate(new_date= if else(date_of_exam-date_of_biopsy<0 == TRUE, date_of_exam[min(n(), 2)], min(date_of_exam). Meaning that if date of exam minus date of biopsy is below 0 then I want to take the 2nd value (as in your solution), if not then the 1st value (i.e.) the lowest. I tried to run the code above, but it did not work... Any idea? It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Phil.He Please don't extend the question after it has been answered. If you have additional question add it as a new question. You can mark this question as answered by accepting the answer clicking on the check mark to the left.